Is it problematic to treat the electron-electron scatterings in plasma under Fokker-Planck approximation?
Fokker Planck equation is widely used in plasma physics to descirbe the time evolution of the plasma in tokamaks (see, e.g., https://www.compxco.com/cql3d_manual.pdf). As known, Fokker-Planck equation is obtained by replacing the collision terms in Boltzmann equation with the Taylor series of the momentum transfer till the second order. It means that Fokker-Planck equation is only valid if the momenta transfer is way smaller than the momenta of the colliding particles. Usually, it is equivalent to say that Fokker-Planck equation is valid for forward (or small angle) scatterings. The plasma physics community usually regard the electron-electron and the electron-ion scatterings as Rutherfold scatterings, which are most probably forward. However, a simple tree level calculation of Feynmann diagram, which is sufficiently precise for $e^2\ll 1$, shows that, electron-electron scatterings can be both forward and backward with equal chance. The detailed differential cross section is shown as follow:
$u$" />
The underlying physics is clear. Quantum mechanics indicates that the forward and backward electron-electron scatterings are indistinguishible, so they must present with the same probability. Fokker-Planck equation is thus no-longer valid in that sense. But is it too suprising to see the influence of quantum mechanics in the plasma physics?

Are you sure that forward scattering means the same thing in the two contexts? As far as I understand, they are not dealing with quantum Boltzmann equation, so there are a bunch of conditions/approximations implied, which are not part of quantum cross-section calculation.

Also, keep in mind that in quantum result the electrons are indistinguishable - so it is logical that the result is symmetric in respect to exchanging thier momenta.

If you are talking about transport+evolution of a momentum distribution function, then using the Fokker-Planck equation is perfectly valid and done all the time.  The collisional operator is treated semi-classically as a non-relativistic Coulomb collision in many cases.  There are relativistic versions of this too which just changes the impact parameter ranges and a few other things.  Again, perfectly okay..
